# Interacting with GRASS GIS vector map topology "level/layers" from terminal/command line?

Tags: grass-gis, topology, command-line

**Can anybody assist in the simplest form of code to call on command line to "export topology" (which is level 2 information in GRASS) as separate spatial data, as explained below?**

I have imported cad lines via dxf file containing only lines (a network of pipelines connected in a geographic pattern) into GRASS GIS via command line.  This data I convert to polylines via GRASS `v.build.polylines` combining individual line segments into polylines in between the connection points. (All "joined" lines that do not intersect with other lines are "concatenated" into a single polyline, thus the network only consists of connected polylines)

The resultant vector map has three "layers" (in GRASS only first "layer", other two as "level") reported by `QGis GRASS Plugin` (seemingly **only** in QGis GUI?)
The "names" assigned to the "level" or "layer" is given by the `QGis GRASS Plugin` as 1:"Line", 2:"line_topo" and 3:"point_topo" and more elaborately,

1. Line -> polylines as expected <<<<<<<<<< termed "map" in GRASS
2. line_topo -> the same polylines, but with node connection table     <<<<<<<< @ level 2 in GRASS without "direct" access
3. point_topo -> the beginning and end points (connection points) of all polylines, with table indicating the lines associated with the specific node   <<<<<<<<<<<<< also @ level 2 in GRASS and also without "direct" access

("direct" access in this context is : a v.?? or similar command -> thus that can "access"/"extract"/"manipulate"/"export"/"or in any form whatsoever make it data that can be worked on outside of GRASS")

These "layers" are reported differently by GRASS (mapname = PipePolyLines):

```
v.info -t map=PipePolyLines
Cleaning up temporary files ...
Starting GRASS ...
Welcome to GRASS 6.4.3 (2013) 
nodes=23274  <<<<<< topology of polyline "connection nodes" (excl vertices)
points=0
lines=25748  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< actual map information
boundaries=0
centroids=0
areas=0
islands=0
faces=0
kernels=0
primitives=25748
map3d=0
Closing monitors ...
```

To clear out the data definition, (as per GRASS definitions)
@ Level 1 :the map has one layer of information being polylines.
@ Level 2 :The topology of these polylines, consisting of a "node table" (listing all the connecting nodes) as well as a table with the "connection detail" (line 1 = from Node1 to Node2, etc).

With the `**GRASS Plugin**` one can load **level 2** topology as "QGis layers" being distinctly either the nodes (as points) or the connecting topology (as lines), with the  NodeFrom and NodeTo line connectivity information.

**How can one export the `line_topo` and the `point_topo` "`QGis GRASS Plugin` layers" (or level 2 topology in GRASS) to shapefile (or even attribute table) making use of external command line tools? (Given that the API function `Vect_set_open_level` seems to be employed by `QGis GRASS Plugin`)**

It is easy to do it within the QGis gui -> simply import from "`QGis GRASS Plugin` layers" and then save from QGis gui. (I was not able to replicate this in the GRASS GUI though.)

**So, how does `QGis GRASS Plugin` avail the topological information as separate accessible "layers", but the same functionality is not available in `GRASS GUI` (and for that matter GRASS)?**

On a Linux system, I have made use of the bash command that exports the command string into an executable *.sh file (marked for execution) as per the GRASS tutorial ("GRASS Batch jobs" [GRASS_and_Shell](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell)).  This functionality allows for bashing also SAGA, where needed, from within the same bash file.

The proof of concept in making this more interactive seems viable and therefore I would much like to be able to interact more extensively with GRASS through the normal command line (outside of GRASS command line).

---

Realizing that there is a function `Vect_set_open_level` from http://grass.osgeo.org/programming6/vector_2Vlib_2open_8c.html, it would seem as if this functionality will not be available at command prompt?

The Grass Plugin for QGis calls this function in `qgsgrassprovider.cpp`.

I am not a programmer so this does not help a lot.

Just to show that GRASS 'v.out.ogr' is not able to access "topo_point" as a layer
all three these commands

1. v.out.ogr -e type=**point** input=PipePolyLines **layer=1** dsn=PolyTopo.shp
2. v.out.ogr -e type=**point** input=PipePolyLines **layer=2** dsn=PolyTopo.shp
3. v.out.ogr -e type=**point** input=PipePolyLines **layer=0** dsn=PolyTopo.shp

produce the same response from GRASS

```
Cleaning up temporary files ...
Starting GRASS ...
Welcome to GRASS 6.4.3 (2013) 
WARNING: 25748 line(s) found, but not requested to be exported. Verify
         'type' parameter.
WARNING: No points found, but requested to be exported. Will skip this
         geometry type.
WARNING: Nothing to export
Closing monitors ...
```

**Can anybody assist with the simplest form of code to call "topology export" from command line as stated above?**

Answer (score 3):

The GRASS command `v.out.ogr`, which you would use to export a vector to a shape, takes a `layer=` parameter. This way you can export separate layers from a GRASS vector. The values would be 0,1 etc.

But when you say "vector map has multiple layers" I assume you mean that the vector contains both points and lines. In this case use the `type=` parameter to get only points or lines.

Comment: Micha, thank you for commenting. Actually, the terminology used in the various modules can become confusing.  I am editing my question in relation to the "vector map has multiple layers".  GRASS uses two distinct terms "layer" and "level" - "layer" for the actual data and "level" for the topology.  Thus, the polyline layer has its topology at level 2 (which is termed "layer" in QGis GRASS plugin).  I want to access "level 2" on "layer 1" as bash printout shows.

Comment: You can find a graphical summary here: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_Database_Management#GRASS_GIS_vector_management_model

Comment: @markusN Thank you for the pointer.  However, not being a programmer, the graphical data presentation does not assist in me accessing the topology information as the programming is way over my head.Seems there is not a ready made function to call from command line in order to extract the topology from GRASS.

Comment: @jacov Not sure what you mean with "extract". To write it out into ASCII format, use http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.out.ascii.html#standard-mode - otherwise v.out.ogr will export to Simple Features (SHAPE is non-topological!).

Comment: @markusN The question is put long in order to convey all communications, but may not be concise enough for a quick read. However, the short and sweet of it is, `my goal, or what I want to achieve, on/at command line can "easily" be achieved from the GRASS Plugin in QGIS`. The process in QGIS is however not suitable for bulk process. So that should eliminate conjecture.  Try for yourself what I describe in the question and your uncertainties might then be cleared up.